# Ubuntu 23.04 Fresh Install Login Loop

Tags: login, 23.04

I have installed Ubuntu 23.04 and am unable to login from a fresh install. I am stuck in the infamous login loop. Xauthority is missing. Things that I have tried:

1. I CAN log in using Wayland, however the HOME folder is empty. I don't know why.

   After reinstalling Ubuntu a few times and trying different things I have come to the realization that:

2. The login loop issue only affects my Ubuntu install when I elect to install the /, swap and /home on separate partitions. If I install it to one partition only, no issues at all.

I am really baffled by this. I didn't experience this issue with Ubuntu 22.04. I am very impressed with the newest iteration of Ubuntu but this basic issue really has me considering my option of falling back to OpenSuse or Linux Mint, both of which I have tested and do not have this issue.

My System:

AMD Ryzen 7 5800x3D
NVIDIA RTX 3070

Comment: A login loop is expected on Linux GUI/desktop systems if lack of space exists in $HOME or the user directory; by using a single partition you have avoided a lack of space in $HOME, but have created it via your split partition layout - we cannot know due to lack of details.  I assume you're talking about a desktop install (*given you didn't actually specify which 23.04 product*)

Comment: "*however the HOME folder is empty*" suggests the possibility the the /home partition is not being mounted. Check for that.

Comment: The parition has plenty of space. / and swap are on an NVME 500gb and my $HOME is on another drive with 1TB space formatted at ext4.

Comment: @user535733, I will check if the /home drive is actually mounted. I'll run another reinstall of the OS. That would be strange for Ubuntu to not mount it. Ive used Ubuntu since Ubuntu 9 and never experience that issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My /home/[user] catalogue wasn't just empty and had root as an owner. I also have a separate /home on NVME drive.

SOLUTION: Login into Wayland and change ownership of /home/[user] from the terminal:

```
sudo chown [user]:[user] /home/[user]/
```

After this, you can reboot and login into the x session without problems.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: There are two methods to fix this I have found after testing extensively.

METHOD 1: Drop to Shell. Login as root and then remove the user account by running `deluser --remove-home username` username being the name of the account. Reboot. You will be greeted with a new screen to setup an account.

METHOD 2: Login via Wayland (Yes, wayland works). Go into settings and Users. Create a new user with administrator privileges. Log out and then log in with the newly created user account. From there you can remove the old user and use the new account or use that account to create a long term account using a username that you originally wanted.