# Ubuntu 23.04 freezing, leading to a login loop - how to investigate?

Tags: login, freeze, 23.04, fuse

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 23.04.

- Used the new installer.
- One 4TB SSD disk with LUKS encryption.

I use the application VideoHubApp, which scans a directory for movies and makes previews.
When I leave this running, most often, this leads to a system freeze, the system restarts automatically, and the next login ends with a login loop.

I can get out of the login loop by re-installing `ubuntu-desktop`.

```
sudo su -
apt remove -y ubuntu-desktop;
apt update;
apt dist-upgrade;
apt autoremove;
apt clean;
apt install -y --fix-missing ubuntu-desktop; 
reboot
```

I did this already 4 times and thinking of writing a script for that :D

But I would prefer to know why the system froze. I can't find anything suspicious in the `journalctl` - at least not what's not there on normal boots.

**How can I investigate what is happening and what prevents Ubuntu to let me log in after such freeze?**

If that matters, as the last thing before this started happening, I installed FUSE and NodeJS which the VideoHubApp needs (not sure why FUSE).

- Lenovo T540p, 16 GB RAM, 4 GB swap.
- Also froze with Ubuntu 20.04 when running this app, but the login loop did not occur.
- 4K display with 150 % fractional scaling
- Not modifications except installing some dev packages - Docker, VirtualBox, etc.

I have seen this question:
[Ubuntu 23.04 Fresh Install Login Loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469321/ubuntu-23-04-fresh-install-login-loop)

But that's not my case - I have just `/boot` and `/`, and home dir is within the same partition with `/`.

Answer (score 4):

I got my answer in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
2023-07-24T04:00:09.789535+02:00 opers kernel: [ 2446.293431] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=systemd-oomd.service,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/dbus.service,task=ffmpeg,pid=21057,uid=1000
2023-07-24T04:00:09.789537+02:00 opers kernel: [ 2446.295850] Out of memory: Killed process 21057 (ffmpeg) total-vm:28821808kB, anon-rss:13241832kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:38296kB oom_score_adj:200
2023-07-24T04:00:09.789549+02:00 opers kernel: [ 2446.609055] rfkill: input handler enabled
2023-07-24T04:00:10.218341+02:00 opers systemd[2611]: dbus.service: A process of this unit has been killed by the OOM killer.
2023-07-24T04:00:10.308724+02:00 opers sh[14704]: Terminated
```

As I suspected, the system runs out of memory. But I wonder why it doesn't kill the APP which ate it all, and kills `dbus.service` instead? Or am I not reading the log properly? Either way, Gnome gets killed, too. Which seems a bit weird choice - to kill the entire desktop environment. Can I prevent that? (A matter for another question.)

As a workaround, I increased my swap file size by 16 GB to 20 GB:

```
sudo swapoff /swap.img 
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap.img bs=16M count=1024 oflag=append conv=notrunc
sudo mkswap /swap.img 
sudo swapon /swap.img
```

Comment: It looks like it does kill ffmpeg first which is probably the app you're running. I'm not sure if it's killing dbus or what that message means. If your app is multi-threaded, reducing the total number of threads may help reduce the total memory usage.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me like dbus is killed at all; rather, like the ffmpeg process was in some kind of a background process started by dbus. And the login loop *after a reboot* caused by any process that was killed doesn't make any sense.
Restarting that background process is probably what crashes your desktop, not the oom-killer.
I'd assume your VideoHubApp installs some autostart part, which gets started when you log in, crashes, and takes your login desktop with it (just like the first time it ran oom), and which gets uninstalled when you uninstall ubuntu-desktop.

Comment: BTW, your swap creation has a typo, surely it should be `20M` instead of `16M` ?

Comment: @GuntramBlohm 1) VideoHubApp is a NodeJS client app, not running in a backgroud; but it runs `ffmpeg` as a sub-process. It does not start with Gnome. Also, it is an `AppImage` if it plays any role.  Whether it restarts `ffmpeg`, that I don't know yet, but there are sources, so I can check.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm, 2)  It is 16M because the Ubuntu installed created 4GB swap automatically, so I am inflating it by 16 GB this way. I guess I could just do `bs=16G count=1` but I just reused some SO answer o:)